# ImportError: cannot import name 'TagHelperNode' from 'django.template.base'

Tags: python, django, python-3.8, django-3.2

I'm facing the error of cannot import name 'TagHelperNode' from 'django.template.base' while im trying to migrate to django 3.2

I know that the problem will be solved if I downgrad django but I can't do that

Answer (score 0):

You can import `TagHelperNode` by :

```
from django.template.library import TagHelperNode
```